# Implementing multi-threading to make two classes run simultaneously

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I will start off by saying that I have looked into how multi-threading works as I think it will help me with the issue that I am having, however I do not really understand how the implementation of it works. Right now, I have my program set up so that when you press a button it triggers MyTask. MyTask runs a counter up to 10 underneath the button and stops when it gets there, once it gets there MyTask1 get's executed which starts a counter counting down from 10 to 0 above the button. The issue that I am having is that in Java things run after one another, but what I want to do is have MyTask and MyTask1 run at the same time instead, so that both counters are happening at once. I think that multi-threading could help me, but I do not really understand how to use it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you everyone.

Code:

```
package com.example.week11;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    Integer count =1;
    Integer count1 =10;
    TextView txt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //p
       //p
       btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       btn.setText("Start");
       txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
       txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View view){
               count =1;
               //p
               //p
               switch (view.getId()){
                   case R.id.button:
                       new MyTask().execute(10);
                       new MyTask1().execute(0);
                       break;
               }
           }
       };
       btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Task Completed.";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            txt.setText(result);
            btn.setText("Restart");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt.setText("Task Starting...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            txt.setText("BackGround Task Running..."+ values[0]);
        }
    }

    class MyTask1 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            for (; count1 >= params[0]; count1--) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(count1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Task Completed.";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            txt1.setText(result);
            btn.setText("Restart");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt1.setText("Task Starting...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            txt1.setText("Countdown "+ values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask` in android runs on single thread until you explicitly specify it to use multiple threads.

In `AsyncTask` source code, you can see the default `Executor` is `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`. Source code: 
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

You can specify `<YourAsyncTask>.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` to make `AsyncTask`s execute paralelly.